# Strange Timezone behaviour Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

Some weirdness here I can't get my head around:

Given these settings:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.TIME_ZONE
'Europe/London'
>>> settings.USE_TZ
False
```

Given the model of:

```
HALF_YEAR = timedelta(days=30*6)

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        from_date = datetime.now() - HALF_YEAR
        return super(ProductManager, self).get_queryset().filter(start_date_time__gt=from_date)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_number = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    cover_renewal_date = models.DateField()
    objects = ProductManager()
```

Which gives us the database table:

```
shopapp=>\d shop_product

        Column         |           Type           |                        Modifiers
-----------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
 id                    | integer                  | not null default nextval('shop_product_id_seq'::regclass)
 product_number        | character varying(45)    | not null
 start_date_time       | timestamp with time zone | not null


shopapp=> show timezone;
 TimeZone
----------
 UTC
(1 row)
```

With the following data:

```
        shopapp=> select product_number, start_date_time 
from shop_product 
where product_number in ('PN63145707', 'PN57284554', 'PN57291674', 'PN66177827');

 product_number | start_date_time
---------------+------------------------
 PN57284554     | 2013-04-05 00:00:00+00
 PN57284554     | 2014-04-05 00:00:00+00
 PN57284554     | 2015-04-05 00:00:00+00
 PN57284554     | 2016-04-05 00:00:00+00
 PN57284554     | 2017-04-05 00:00:00+00
 PN57291674     | 2013-04-04 00:00:00+00
 PN57291674     | 2014-04-04 00:00:00+00
 PN57291674     | 2015-04-04 00:00:00+00
 PN57291674     | 2016-04-04 00:00:00+00
 PN57291674     | 2017-04-04 00:00:00+00
 PN63145707     | 2015-03-25 00:00:00+00
 PN63145707     | 2016-03-25 00:00:00+00
 PN63145707     | 2017-03-25 00:00:00+00
 PN66177827     | 2017-03-25 00:00:00+00
(14 rows)
```

But running this code:

```
now = datetime.now().date()
start_time = now - timedelta(days=1)
end_time = now + timedelta(days=14)
res = Product.objects.filter(start_date_time__range=(start_time, end_time), product_number__in=['PN63145707', 'PN57284554', 'PN57291674', 'PN66177827'])
for item in res:
    print(item.product_number, str(item.start_date_time))
```

Gives me the result

```
(u'PN63145707', '2017-03-25 00:00:00')
(u'PN57284554', '2017-04-05 01:00:00')
(u'PN57291674', '2017-04-04 01:00:00')
(u'PN66177827', '2017-03-25 00:00:00')
```

It appears any start_date_time beyond BST (26th march) is showing with a time of 1AM.  Why is this if the USE_TZ is set to False?

Thanks.

Versions:
django-1.10.4,
postgresql psql (9.4.10, server 9.6.1)

**EDIT**:
When I run the same code, with the same settings, on our test server the results are not the same:

```
In [20]: settings.TIME_ZONE
Out[20]: 'Europe/London'

In [21]: settings.USE_TZ
Out[21]: False

(u'PN63145707', '2017-03-25 00:00:00')
(u'PN66177827', '2017-03-25 00:00:00')
(u'PN57291674', '2017-04-04 00:00:00')
(u'PN57284554', '2017-04-05 00:00:00')
```

Why are these records not being adjusted to the Europe/London timezone like the values on the production server?

Comment: forgot to say - (rather obviously) - I don't see this behaviour locally, only after i've deployed to production.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you're seeing is exactly as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#postgresql).  It is a by-product of Django's insistence on using a postgresql `timestamptz` rather than `timestamp`.

Internally, a Postgresql `timestamptz` stores the datetime in UTC.  When queried it then returns the timestamp converted to the requestor's timezone.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/timezones/#postgresql) notes that when `USE_TZ` is set to `false` the database connections timezone will be set to `TIMEZONE` (or Europe/London in your case).  This will cause **Postgresql to convert the UTC timestamps stored to London time** before giving them to Django.

Comment: Understood. From what your saying the prod server is behaving correctly (i agree).  However please see my edit - I guess the question is would the test server fail to convert back into the timezone

Comment: I think I know why, the test server is running on Ubuntu 14.04 the Prod is running Ubuntu 16.04 - could there be difference in OS timezone settings?

Comment: In your test server case, check what the actual utc dates in postgresql are ... `timestamptz` is a devil to dare with, it converts the date to UTC when its stored (using the connections timezone if none is on the date itself), and then back again when you query for it.  If you're not using the same timezone across dev/prod for **both insertion and selection** you'll see differences between the systems.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.now()` returns the current local date and time, in your case it is returning you the production server date and time. Either you should convert that to your specific timezone `Europe/London` or you can use `django.utils.timezone.now` which will respect your `settings.py` configurations:

```
from django.utils import timezone
now = timezone.now().date()
```

Note that [django.utils.timezone.now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) behaves differently based on the value of `USE_TZ`